# Flutter provider how to close every instance

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm using the Provider package with Flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/provider) + Firebase Auth + Firestore and I'm facing a problem with Streams I can't solve. Here is some code:

In my main.dart

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        InheritedProvider<FeedController>(create: (_) => FeedController()),
        ... others 
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(...)
    ...
}
```

My FeedController hosts multiples Streams like those two examples:

```dart
final _feedData = StreamController<QuerySnapshot>();
Stream<QuerySnapshot> get feedData => _feedData.stream;

or

Stream<QuerySnapshot> loadTags() async* {
    yield* _database.retrieveUserTags(await _auth.retrieveUserUid());
}
```

My problem is when I'm logging out of Firebase, as I'm not authenticated I'm having "PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions". I know why: my streams are not closed and as I'm logged out I don't have the right to read data from Firebase (I've blocked unauth reads). I'd just want to close every instance passed by Provider BEFORE logging out then calling my logging out function. Any ideas of how could I do it? It's just in the logs but I'd like to solve the problem.

I've tried to do something like that:

In my FeedController

```dart
 // Closing all Streams
  void dispose() {
    _isLoadingController.close();
    _feedData.close();
    _newData.close();
  }
```

And calling before logging out:

```dart
Provider.of<FeedController>(context, listen: false).dispose();
```

But I'm having errors saying I can't add data after a Stream is closed even If I'm not trying to add data to closed Streams..

Thank you

Comment: One thing I didn't mentionned: I use "bool get wantKeepAlive => true;" on my pages so they're not refreshed every time I switch tabs so I guess that's why I've the problem with my streams?

Comment: Did you try closing your streams in the dispose method of a StatefulWidget?

Comment: The thing is that the dispose method is not called as I use KeppAlive to prevent reloading after tab changes

Comment: I got another suggestion, try toggling `wantKeepAlive` by using a ChangeNotifier or similar approach, This might to the job.

Comment: Actually that's a good idea, will give it a try, thanks :)

Comment: Crazyman60 Did it work?

Comment: did you solve this?